# Rank mismatch in argument when Overloading in fortran

Tags: fortran, overloading

I have a Vector derived type

```
   Type :: Vector

     Real (Real32),  Allocatable :: r32(:)
     Real (Real64),  Allocatable :: r64(:)
     Real (Real128), Allocatable :: r128(:) 

   Contains

     Procedure :: set => vector_set,    & 
                         vector_tutvc,  &
                         vector_vctvc
```

If I call the subroutine as in (a) I get everything working 
correctly, however when using (b) I am getting

Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'u' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)

```
(a) Call vcr % vector_tutvc (r)

(b) Call vcr % set (r)
```

Here are more details

```
 Subroutine vector_set (t, u, v, w)
   Class (Vector), Intent(InOut) :: t
   Class (*), Intent (In) :: u
   Class (*), Intent (In), Optional :: v, w

 Subroutine vector_tutvc (u, tu)
   Class (Vector), Intent(InOut) :: u
   Class (*), Intent (In) :: tu(:)
```

Here is code for test program

```
 Type (Vector) :: vcr
 Real (Real32), Allocatable :: r(:)

 r = [                                                    &
   1.0000000, 0.9999965, 0.9999931, 0.9999896, 0.9999862,  &
   0.9999829, 0.9999796, 0.9999763, 0.9999731, 0.9999699,  &
   0.9999668, 0.9999637, 0.9999607                         &
 ]

 Call vcr % set (r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the type-bound procedure declaration

```
procedure :: binding => procedure
```

the type-bound procedure `procedure` has the binding name `binding`.

From your mention of overloading and your choice of indentation, it seems like you expect the statement

```
Procedure :: set => vector_set,    & 
                    vector_tutvc,  &
                    vector_vctvc
```

to be such that the binding name `set` is generic, referring to each of those procedures.  In fact, the statement above is the same as

```
Procedure :: set          => vector_set,    & 
             vector_tutvc => vector_tutvc,  &
             vector_vctvc => vector_vctvc
```

To establish overloading, you need to use a generic binding, such as

```
Procedure :: vector_set, vector_tutvc,vector_vctvc
Generic :: set => vector_set, vector_tutvc, vector_vctvc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    module type_Vector

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: &
        sp => REAL32, &
        dp => REAL64, &
        qp => REAL128

    ! Explicit typing only
    implicit none

    ! Everything is private unless stated otherwise
    private
    public :: Vector

    ! Declare derived data type
    type, public :: Vector
        real (sp), allocatable :: r32(:)
        real (dp), allocatable :: r64(:)
        real (qp), allocatable :: r128(:)
    contains
        procedure, private :: vector_set
        procedure, private :: vector_tutvc
        generic,   public  :: set => &
            vector_set, &
            vector_tutvc
    end type Vector

contains

    subroutine vector_set(this, u, v, w)
        class (Vector),      intent(in out) :: this
        class (*),           intent (in)    :: u
        class (*), optional, intent (in)    :: v
        class (*), optional, intent (in)    :: w
    end subroutine vector_set

    subroutine vector_tutvc(this, tu)
        class (Vector), intent (in out) :: this
        class (*),      intent (in)     :: tu(:)
    end subroutine vector_tutvc

end module type_Vector

program main

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: &
        sp => REAL32, &
        stdout => OUTPUT_UNIT, &
        compiler_version, &
        compiler_options

    use type_Vector, only: &
        Vector

    ! Explicit typing only
    implicit none

    type (Vector)          :: vcr
    real (sp), allocatable :: r(:)

    r = [ &
        1.0000000_sp, 0.9999965_sp, 0.9999931_sp, 0.9999896_sp, 0.9999862_sp, &
        0.9999829_sp, 0.9999796_sp, 0.9999763_sp, 0.9999731_sp, 0.9999699_sp, &
        0.9999668_sp, 0.9999637_sp, 0.9999607_sp &
        ]

    call vcr%set(r)

    write( stdout, '(/4A/)' ) 'This file was compiled by ', &
        compiler_version(), ' using the options ', &
        compiler_options()

end program main
```

`set` is now a `generic` type-bound procedure.

```
This file was compiled by GCC version 5.3.1 20160528 using the options -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O3 -std=f2008ts
```